Onprem - Exchange Shared-Mailbox mails stuck in outbox
an user in my company has the error, that there are mails stuck in the outbox, that don't let to delete themselve. I've recognized, that when I connect the shared-mailbox as an account and send mails directly from the account, the mails also get stuck in the outbox and won't leave the outbox - or let delete, or move, or archive themselves. BUT when I remove the shared mailbox as an account and send mails with the "send from" button, new sended Mails won't get stuck in the outbox. Anyways, the mails in the outbox from the shared-mailbox are still in there, and I can't get them out and I'm running out of ideas. What I've tried:
Removed the profile and cleared all Caches, several times.
Tried to remove the Mails with MFCMAPI
Connected to remove the Mails from my account, separate pc - Didn't see any mails in the outbox.
Removed the permissions on the shared mailbox, and enabled it again - didn't work.
Any Ideas, what I could also try?
THX!

Solution:
I went from an external network and added the shared-mailbox as an account.
Then, I switched the active account to the shared mailbox and was then able to delete it.
Idk why it worked, but it worked!

It sounds like your email is stuck in the outbox and won't be transferred to the sent items.
You can see the solution from the article below first.This may seem a bit tedious.
Email stays in Outbox until manually send or receive
Outlook Emails Stuck in Outbox? 15 Ways and 11 Checks to Try
Outlook email stuck
Also,as far as,FIOS routers have some issues with IPv6,and you can try disabling the router with IPv6 support.

Hey! Didnt work, but I found a solution.
